# Add a prefix to all media links in a html file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I'm trying to insert an absolute path before all images in an HTML file, like this:

```
<img src="/media/some_path/some_image.png"> to <img src="{ABS_PATH}/some_path/some_image.png">
```

I tried the following regex to identify the lines :

```
egrep '(src|href)="/media([^"]*)"'
```

I want to use sed to make these changes, but the above regexp doesn't work, any hints?

```
 sed 's#(src|href)="/media([^"]*)"##g'
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'

EDIT:
ok, now i have:

```
echo 'src="/media/some_image.png"' | "egrep -o '(src|href)="/media([^"]*)"' | sed 's/(src|href)=\"\/media([^"]*)\"//g'
```

Sed should match the string, but it doesn't

Comment: change \"\/media([^"]*)\" to "\/media([^"]*)", there was an error in my original answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. sed doesn't understand ERE (extended regular expressions), only BRE (basic regular expressions). GNU sed has "-r" option which turn on ERE.
2. You should change delimiters for regular expressions, because you have slash in the regex, like this:

   ```
   sed -r 's#(src|href)="/media([^"]*)"##g'
   ```

You can use almost any punctuation for delimiters.

Comment: The above expression can be written: `sed 's#\(src\|href\)="/media[^"]*"##g'`. N.B. I've removed the second grouping as it held no use.

Answer (score 1):

You must escape `/` in sed if using it as a delimiter for the pattern.

So:

```
sed 's/(src|href)="/media([^"]*)"//g'
```

becomes:

```
sed 's/(src|href)="\/media([^"]*)"//g'
```

Perhaps what is confusing is that egrep (which uses extended regular expressions) has different rules to sed, and vanilla grep (which use basic regular expressions) when it comes to what must be escaped.

Comment: No need to escape double quotes.